# Keras model giving 87% accuracy but not accurate real time results

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using the [mnist sign language dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datamunge/sign-language-mnist) for the model training.  The model is training well and the accuracy is good enough but it fails on real-time predictions. Also if somebody could also guide how to use this model for camera-based real-time gestures, in order to perform certain tasks.

On a second note is it a good idea to use csv dataset for images rather than actual images for model training. Does it impact the accuracy of the model.

```
"""AlmostFinal.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bjW72xyST8i2WAzRYj7qXoRPRgID5XZJ
"""

pip install kaggle

from google.colab import files
files.upload()

!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600  ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle datasets download -d datamunge/sign-language-mnist

from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = 'sign-language-mnist.zip'
with ZipFile(file_name,'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall()
  print('done')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv("/content/sign_mnist_train.csv").values
test  = pd.read_csv("/content/sign_mnist_test.csv").values



trainX = train[:, 1:].reshape(train.shape[0],28,28,1).astype( 'float32' )
X_train = trainX / 255.0

y_train = train[:,0]


# Reshape and normalize test data
testX = test[:,1:].reshape(test.shape[0],28,28,1).astype( 'float32' )
X_test = testX / 255.0

y_test = test[:,0]

from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
y_train = lb.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = lb.fit_transform(y_test)

print(X_test.shape[1:])
print(y_test.shape[1:])

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Convolution2D(50,(3,3),input_shape=(28,28,1),activation='relu',padding='same'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2),padding='same'),
        layers.Convolution2D(250,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(250, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(24,activation='softmax')
    ]
)


#model.add(Convolution2D(30, 3, 3, border_mode= 'valid' , input_shape=(28, 28, 1),activation= 'relu', dim_ordering='tf' ))
##model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dense(24, activation= 'softmax' ))

model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' , metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

#model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' , metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,batch_size = 20,verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)

print(score)
print("test loss, test acc:", score)

predictions = model.predict()

import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2


uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  path = fn

  #img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(28, 28),color_mode="grayscale")
  #x = tf.image.resize_images(fn, (28, 28),)
  
  image = cv2.imread(fn)
  new_image = cv2.imread(fn,0)
  new_image = cv2.resize(image,(28,28))
  x = np.expand_dims(new_image,axis = 3)
  
  #x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=3)


  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(classes)

print(classes)
```

The accuracy is 87% but the realtime results are not good.

Comment: where does this images come from that you are trying to predict,is it from the same MNIST dataset?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat The plan is to make this model predict live images from a webcam. But in my code, I was trying to upload images from my computer.

Comment: yes,the prediction could be bad for the data,if the data is not come from the same test and train data sample,what you could do is to check if the images from your local files preprocessed before feeding into model,you could train your model with these local files too make it more robust,or you could use data augmentation,do checkout other resources too

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I am using csv files instead of real images in my dataset. Also I have trained the model for train and test data. It is just that there is some problem in the code due to which the model is not giving good predictions on real images. Can you guide me a resource on how to do data augmentation on CSV images

Comment: what do you mean by csv images,is the pixel values are mentioned in the csv files as rows and columns?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat, Yes there are 785 columns(pixel1,pixel2,pixel3,pixel4...pixel784) and first column is labels from 1-24. There are almost 27000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case does not match the data your model has been trained on. Try adding some of your own images into the dataset or create your own dataset. Also, try adding some generalization techniques like data augmentation, weight decay etc.